# Getting the active IP in Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ip

I'm trying to get the IP address of the computer that's connected to the Internet. I tried this:

```
var netInterfaces:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInfo.networkInfo.findInterfaces();
var addresses:Vector.<InterfaceAddress> = netInterfaces[0].addresses;
var userIp:String = addresses[0].address;
```

But this code gives me a lot of IP addresses, I want the application itself to determine the IP connected to the internet, so how to do so??

Answer (score 0):

You can always just load a page that tells your IP (something like http://www.whatismyip.org/) and grab the data from there.